# Overwrite and restore a function

Tags: javascript, function

I need to mock call a function in JavaScript. For this, I'm "saving" the function in a temporary variable, update the target with a new function block, calling the target and then restoring the old function:

```js
var myObject = {
  myIntProp: 1,
  myFunc: function(value) {
    alert(value + 1);
  }
};
myObject.myFunc(2);

var tmp = myObject.myFunc;
myObject.myFunc = function(value) {
  alert(value - 1);
};
myObject.myFunc(2);

myObject.myFunc = tmp;
myObject.myFunc(2);
```

This works as expected: the function gets overwritten and then successfully restored. My thought was to move this code into a helper function and easily use it when needed:

```js
function FunctionSwapper(target, newFunction) {
  var old = target;
  target = newFunction;
  this.Restore = function() {
    target = old;
  }
};

var myObject = {
  myIntProp: 1,
  myFunc: function(value) {
    alert(value + 1);
  }
};
myObject.myFunc(2);

var swapp = new FunctionSwapper(myObject.myFunc, function(value) {
  alert(value - 1);
});
myObject.myFunc(2);

swapp.Restore();
myObject.myFunc(2);
```

This code however, does not save the current state nor is it replacing the targeted function. What am I missing here? Isn't a function always passed as reference? What are the main differences between the two code snippets?

([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/oc1xhc9j/) available, but prepare for 8 `alert`s...)

Edit: a fellow user has pointed out that the second method does not really differ from the first one and that it's probably not worth the trouble of creating the additional class; while I do understand and agree with their arguments, I see two advantages in the second method (both apply to my *particular*, real-world case):

1. it's easier/faster to write `swapp.Restore();` than `myNameSpace.level2.level3.level4.level5 = swap;` when working with objects which have several levels of child elements and,
2. it abstracts the operation, providing a consistent use among the development team (additionally, logging or type proofing could be done inside the class).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This happens because `target` is not a true reference, it is a value which references `target` function.

However when you reassign target, you do not modify the held value (the reference to the function), but you modify the value directly, which means you can't do it this way.

Instead you can pass the object holding the function to replace (it would only work with an object, since you need to access it later).

Here is what I came up with

```
function FunctionSwapper(target, name, newFunction) {
  var old = target[name];
  target[name] = newFunction;
  this.Restore = function() {
    target[name] = old;
  }
};

var myObject = {
  myIntProp: 1,
  myFunc: function(value) {
    alert(value + 1);
  }
};
myObject.myFunc(2);

var swapp = new FunctionSwapper(myObject, 'myFunc', function(value) {
  alert(value - 1);
});
myObject.myFunc(2);

swapp.Restore();
myObject.myFunc(2);
```

Comment: Ah, you beat me by 15 seconds apparently with an almost identical answer!

Answer (score 3):

The `FunctionSwapper` is restoring its own copy of the function, but it has no connection to `myObject` (you don't pass it a reference to `myObject`).

This would work:

```
function FunctionSwapper(object,name,newFunction) {
  var old = object[name];
  object[name] = newFunction;
  this.Restore = function() {
    object[name] = old;
  }
};
```

...

```
var swapp = new FunctionSwapper(myObject, "myFunc", function(value) {
  alert(value - 1);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

I believe by passing in `myObject.myFunc`, you actually break the reference from the `myObject`, so it doesn't actually update the `myFunc` call of `myObject`, it updates the local scope of the `FunctionSwapper`'s copy.

Compare it to this, which carries out the operation on the object itself:

```
function FunctionSwapper(obj, funcName, newFunction) {
    var old = obj[funcName];
    obj[funcName] = newFunction;
    this.Restore = function() {
        obj[funcName] = old;
    }
};

var myObject = {
  myIntProp: 1,
  myFunc: function(value) {
    alert(value + 1);
  }
};
myObject.myFunc(2);

var swapp = new FunctionSwapper(myObject, "myFunc", function(value) {
  alert(value - 1);
});
myObject.myFunc(2);

swapp.Restore();
myObject.myFunc(2);
```